# Can IDL create a contour plot colorbar like this?

Tags: colors, plot, contour, idl-programming-language

At the bottom of this image, you'll see a nice colorbar that matches the colors of the graph correctly:

http://stribog.cc.umanitoba.ca/ceos/20100517_00z_prod/

I couldn't find anything that created a color bar with exactly the colors I wanted, it always seemed to involve a spectrum that included colors I didn't use.

I have a vector of colors I use for my data. Is there I way I can use that vector to create a color bar with only those colors?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure it can be done.  In fact that sample plot looks suspiciously like IDL.  Post some sample code of what you're doing now, I may be able to help, but starting from scratch is too hard.